# Joining lines based on star char (*)

Tags: unix, awk, sed, gawk

I have text file having lines where few lines starting with "i" some with "u>i" and other as "?" and there are always 2 lines below these lines and I want to join these 2 lines (append) with lines having anywhere "".

Tried awk, sed but not getting exact string which can solve this.

File Data :-

```
*i    80.95.226.72/29                                    n/a         None

    193.105.101.26                                     None        -
    28834 64690

*?    85.118.193.0/25                                    n/a         None

    193.105.101.26                                     None        -
    28834 64814

u*>i  213.226.55.0/24                                    n/a         None

    193.105.101.27                                     None        -
    28834 64757

*i    80.65.79.160/27                                    n/a         None
    193.105.101.26                                     None        -
    28834 9146
```

Expected Output :-

```
*i,80.95.226.72/29,n/a,None,193.105.101.26 ,None,-,28834,64690
*?,85.118.193.0/25,n/a,None,193.105.101.26 ,None,-,28834,64814
u*>i,213.226.55.0/24,n/a,None193.105.101.27 ,None,-,28834,9146
```

Comment: Please edit the layout properly. Paint the data with your mouse and click the `{}` in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

**awk** solution, works no matter the number of fields in any of the lines, is:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{OFS=","}
NF && p && !/\*/ { p = p OFS coalesce(); next}
/\*/{ if (p) print p; p=coalesce()}0
function coalesce(){
   s=""
   for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) s=s (i==NF ? $i : $i OFS)
   return s
}
```

**Explanation**:

```
BEGIN{OFS=","}                         # set Output Field Separator to ","
NF && p && !/\*/ {                     # if nr of fields > 0, not containing 
                                       # '*' and p is set
    p = p OFS coalesce(); next         # add formatted $0 to p
} 
/\*/{                                  # if $0 contains '*'
    if (p) print p;                    #   if p then print it
    p=coalesce()                       #   initialize p
}0                                     # ignore rest of lines
function coalesce(){
   s=""
   for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) s=s (i==NF ? $i : $i OFS)
   return s
}
```

**Testing**:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk input.txt
*i,80.95.226.72/29,n/a,None,193.105.101.26,None,-,28834,64690
*?,85.118.193.0/25,n/a,None,193.105.101.26,None,-,28834,64814
u*>i,213.226.55.0/24,n/a,None,193.105.101.27,None,-,28834,64757
```

Or as **oneliner**:

```
$ awk -v OFS=, '$0 && p && !/\*/ { p = p OFS coalesce(); next}/\*/{ if (p) print p; p=coalesce()}0;function coalesce(){s="";for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) s=s (i==NF ? $i : $i OFS);return s}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

**One-liner** `awk`

```
$ awk -v OFS=, 'NF{$1=$1; s=(s?s OFS:"") $0}NF==2 && s{print s; s=""}' infile
```

**To address your post title:**

```
awk -v OFS=, -v n=2 'NF{$1=$1}/\*/{s=$0;next}s && NF && n>=c++{s = s OFS $0}c==n{print s; s=c=""}' infile
```

**Better Readable:**

```
awk -v OFS=, -v n=2 '
                     NF{ 
                          $1 = $1 
                       }
                   /\*/{
                          s=$0
                          next 
                       }
      s && NF && n>=c++{
                           s = s OFS $0
                       }
                   c==n{
                           print s 
                           s = c = ""
                       }
                    ' infile
```

**Explanation:**

> - `NF{ $1 = $1 }`
>
> If line/record/row has at least one field ( `NF` gives no of fields in
>   record ), then recompile record, because when you do `$1=$1` (or any
>   other assignment to a field) it causes record recompilation where `$0`
>   is rebuilt with every `FS` replaced with `OFS`.
>
> - `/\*/{ s = $0; next }`
>
> If line contains `*` then assign variable `s` with current
>   record/row/line, and go to next line.
>
> - `s && NF && n>=c++{ s = s OFS $0 }`
>
> If variable `s` is set, and record has at least 1 field and variable
>   `n` is greater than or equal to variable `c++` (`++`  increment
>   operator), then concatenate variable `s`
>
> - `c==n{print s; s=c=""}`
>
> If variable `c` equal to variable `n` then print variable `s`, and
>   nullify variable `s` and `c`

**Input:**

```
$ cat infile
*i 80.95.226.72/29 n/a None

  193.105.101.26                                     None        -
  28834 64690

*? 85.118.193.0/25 n/a None

  193.105.101.26                                     None        -
  28834 64814

u*>i 213.226.55.0/24 n/a None

  193.105.101.27                                     None        -
  28834 64757
```

**Output-1:**

```
$ awk -v OFS=, 'NF{$1=$1; s=(s?s OFS:"") $0}NF==2 && s{print s; s=""}' infile
*i,80.95.226.72/29,n/a,None,193.105.101.26,None,-,28834,64690
*?,85.118.193.0/25,n/a,None,193.105.101.26,None,-,28834,64814
u*>i,213.226.55.0/24,n/a,None,193.105.101.27,None,-,28834,64757
```

**Output-2:**

```
$ awk -v OFS=, -v n=2 'NF{$1=$1}/\*/{s=$0;next}s && NF && n>=c++{s = s OFS $0}c==n{print s; s=c=""}' infile
*i,80.95.226.72/29,n/a,None,193.105.101.26,None,-,28834,64690
*?,85.118.193.0/25,n/a,None,193.105.101.26,None,-,28834,64814
u*>i,213.226.55.0/24,n/a,None,193.105.101.27,None,-,28834,64757
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following awk too.

```
awk 'NF{gsub(/ +/,",");printf("%s",!/^,/?(NR!=1?RS $0:$0):$0)} END{print ""}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
*i,80.95.226.72/29,n/a,None,193.105.101.26,None,-,28834,64690
*?,85.118.193.0/25,n/a,None,193.105.101.26,None,-,28834,64814
u*>i,213.226.55.0/24,n/a,None,193.105.101.27,None,-,28834,64757
```

Adding explanation and a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
NF{                                       ##If a line is NON-empty then do following steps.
  gsub(/ +/,",");                         ##Globally substituting all continuous spaces with a single comma in each non-empty line.
  printf("%s",!/^,/?(NR!=1?RS $0:$0):$0)  ##printing line here with a condition if line number is NOT equal to 1 and starts with comma then print RS(whose default value is a new line and current line) else print current line, outer else print current line.
}
END{
  print ""                                ##Printing NULL value here to print a new line.
}
' Input_file                              ##Mentioning Input_file name here too.
```